# Absolute equivalent of a synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I was debugging a program and I solved the bug by putting synchronized in 2 different methods. Strangely, before that, I've used locks, but with no success.

```
public void method()    
{
    lock.lock(); //lock
    if(nReaders > 0){

    readers.await(); }//await

    nReaders++;



    ...


    nReaders--;

    readers.signal(); //signal
    lock.unlock(); //lock
}
```

I thought that this was equivalent to this

```
public synchronized void method(){}
```

but unfortunately it doesn't seem the case... what am I missing here?

Comment: Without knowing the definition of `lock` and how its scope relates to the threads, it will be hard to provide an answer.

Comment: Lock/Unlock must *always* be in [try/catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)

Answer (score 2):

One locks on a concrete Lock object, and the other locks on `this`, and that is a big difference, especially if the lock object is the same for all instances of this class. If there are multiple instances of this object, then each instance will lock on itself, which may not be what you want.

Comment: so synchronized method(){} is equivalent to method(){this.lock() ... this.unlock()}?

Comment: No, there is no this.lock(). It's equivalent to `synchronized (this) method() {}`

Comment: then we have no choice of using synchronized right? i mean between synchronized (this) and synchronized method() there is not much difference

Comment: @fogofwar: please clarify your last statement as I'm having trouble parsing the meaning from it.